# Detect intersections of lines with rectangles

Tags: java, line, intersection, point, rectangles

[image]

I want to detect intersection points of random lines with random rectangels.
My Line class get 4 coordinates and makes a line out of them.
My intersectionWith function gets 2 lines and returns the intersection point, and if there is no point, it returns null.

I have 2 functions:
One finds the closest intersection point and returns it (I think it's irrelevant here):
Located in Line.java

```
public Point closestIntersectionToStartOfLine(Rectangle rect){
    Line[] rectLines = new Line[4];
    Point[] IntersectionPoints = new Point[4];
    double minDistance=0;
    //up
    rectLines[0] = new Line(rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY(), rect.getWidth()+rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY());
    //right
    rectLines[1] = new Line(rect.getWidth()+rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY(), rect.getUpperLeft().getX()+rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()+rect.getUpperLeft().getY());
    //down
    rectLines[2] = new Line(rect.getUpperLeft().getX()+rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()+rect.getUpperLeft().getY(), rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY()+rect.getHeight());
    //left
    rectLines[3] = new Line(rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY()+rect.getHeight(), rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY());

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if (intersectionWith(rectLines[i]) != null)
            IntersectionPoints[i] = intersectionWith(rectLines[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<IntersectionPoints.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            minDistance = rect.getUpperLeft().distance(IntersectionPoints[i]);
        else {
            if (rect.getUpperLeft().distance(IntersectionPoints[i]) < minDistance)
                Point.closestIntersectionToStartOfLine = IntersectionPoints[i];
        }
    }
    return Point.closestIntersectionToStartOfLine;
}
```

And this function keep ALL intersection points of a given line into a list.
Located in Rectangle.java

```
 // Return a (possibly empty) List of intersection points
// with the specified line.
public java.util.List<Point> intersectionPoints(Line line) {
    List<Point> intersectionPointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Line[] rectangleSides = new Line[4];
    Point[] corners = new Point[4];
    rectangleCorners(corners);
    recatngleSides(rectangleSides, corners);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Point p = line.intersectionWith(rectangleSides[i]);
        if (p != null && !intersectionPointsList.contains(p)) {
            intersectionPointsList.add(p);
        }
    }
    return intersectionPointsList;
}
public void rectangleCorners(Point[] corners) {
    double width = this.getWidth();
    double height = this.getHeight();
    double x = this.upperLeft.getX();
    double y = this.upperLeft.getY();
    //upper left
    corners[0] = this.getUpperLeft();
    //upper right
    corners[1] = new Point(x + width, y);
    //down right
    corners[2] = new Point(x + width, y + height);
    //down left
    corners[3] = new Point(x, y + height);
}

/**
 * recatngleSides.
 * Saves the lines in the 4 rectangle edges.
 *
 * @param sides  - an empty array of lines
 * @param corners - an array of edge points.
 */
public void recatngleSides(Line[] sides, Point[] corners) {
    // up
    sides[0] = new Line(corners[0], corners[1]);
    // right
    sides[1] = new Line(corners[1], corners[2]);
    // down
    sides[2] = new Line(corners[2], corners[3]);
    // left
    sides[3] = new Line(corners[3], corners[0]);
}
```

}

I don't know why but it recognises random points as intersection points as you can see in the picture.

Comment: It looks like you've over complicated things. Try starting off with creating a method that tests intersection between 2 lines, test it, and then use it 4 times to test a line against a rectangle.

Comment: but this is exactly what I have wrote. "My intersectionWith function gets 2 lines and returns the intersection point, and if there is no point, it returns null." This function 100% works because I tested it on 2 lines. and now i'm trying to implant it on a rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, if you look where your 'random' points are, they are actually where the sides of non-intersecting rectangles would be if you extend the sides to infinity. You need to actually check there is an intersection with the line segment that is the rectangle side.

Comment: Oh you are right! Wait so why the checking part isn't working? I mean I do check there is an intersection.  
        if (p != null && !intersectionPointsList.contains(p)) {
            intersectionPointsList.add(p);

Comment: I think you are just finding the intersection between the mathematical lines. Any lines that are not parallel will intersect somewhere. So you need to check where the intersection point is and whether that is also between the start and end of the line.

Comment: dude thanks alot! I did a stupid mistake of treating this as infinite lines and not as sigments.

Comment: No problem, it's an easy thing to do.